# Does God intend or call some people to live alone forever in their life?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, free-will, will-of-god, singleness

No. I am not talking about taking the sacrament of priesthood or brotherhood or being a nun who is called to live a holy life only for Christ.

I mean if a man tries hard to find a partner but it seems he is always failing in his life to find a partner so, in that case, is that man called by God to live alone forever as long as he lives, spend time praying to God and serve the people of the society by good, generous, loving, caring, and honest deeds? Is not taking the sacrament of marriage a sin even when it's not his choice?

I could be wrong but I saw statistics that about 0.99999% of people around the world would never have a relationship. So this question.

Comment: Possibly, but if so he doesn't tell us directly. Instead the NT teaches that singleness is a normal state - we're all born single, and over half of everyone who gets married will be single again, either from death or divorce. We're called to contentment, which is not always easy, and to seek satisfaction in our relationship with God. But God may use all that time to prepare us for a relationship in later life.

Comment: @curiousdannii Very balanced : agreed. _Therefore, I say to the unmarried and to the widows: It is good for them if they remain even as I am; neveretheless etc._

Comment: Matthew 19:10-12 the gift of singleness

Comment: Question is filled with internal contradictions and assumptions.  Badly constructed.

Comment: We need to be clear that "single" is not a synonym for "alone".  The Church is not supposed to let single people live in isolation.

Comment: @curiousdannii Scripture also teaches that both death and divorce are not what God intended.  Singleness, as God intends it, is a special calling in a fallen world, not the target.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Does God intend or call some people to live alone forever in their life?**

The short answer is that it is **very possible**.

There are [four basic states of life](https://our-vocations.weebly.com/types-of-vocations.html) within the Catholic Church: marriage, consecrated life, priesthood and the single state as an unmarried lay person.

Trying to find one’s true vocation in life is for some individuals a task that will engulf their entire life.

Only at the end of earthly journey in this world, will some truly know if God really intended some to live single their whole life long. It may be thus true or it may not. When we see Our Lord on the day of our own particular judgement, it will all be revealed. For some, the answer will be yes. For others it will be no, for God will show to us where we may have gone astray in our true vocation.

> Pope John Paul II, who wanted to be known as ‘the Pope of the family’, wrote in his familial document “Familiaris Consortio” that those without a family must be able to find their family within the Church. In fact, the entire final section of this document is dedicated to single people.
>
> This is a subject with which John Paul II would have been intimately familiar – by the age of 20, all of his immediate family on earth had passed away, and he surrounded himself with good friends that essentially became his family.
>
> In the document, he wrote: “For those who have no natural family the doors of the great family which is the Church - the Church which finds concrete expression in the diocesan and the parish family, in ecclesial basic communities and in movements of the apostolate - must be opened even wider. No one is without a family in this world: the Church is a home and family for everyone, especially those who 'labor and are heavy laden.'”
>
> The Catechism of the Catholic also recognizes “the great number of single persons who, because of the particular circumstances in which they have to live – often not of their choosing – are especially close to Jesus' heart and therefore deserve the special affection and active solicitude of the Church, especially of pastors.” (CCC 1658). -[Is the single life a vocation? Maybe we're asking the wrong question.](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/is-the-single-life-a-vocation-maybe-were-asking-the-wrong-question-68948)

I would like simply mention here two things. It 
would be good to talk to a priest or pastor about this subject matter. They may have some valuable insights in helping one discerning things in life. Secondly, vocations are a challenge. Even Pope St. John Paul II, at one time, considered getting married before entering the seminary. He was young, healthy and handsome. He spoke to his spiritual director and followed the promptings of the Holy Spirit.

The states of life are never easy.

Once again the answer to your question is **possibly**!

Let us here simply recall the words of Jesus to his Apostles:

> 10 His disciples say unto him, If the case of the man be so with his wife, it is not good to marry.
>
> 11 But he said unto them, All men cannot receive this saying, save they to whom it is given.
>
> 12 For there are some eunuchs, which were so born from their mother's womb: and there are some eunuchs, which were made eunuchs of men: and there be eunuchs, which have made themselves eunuchs for the kingdom of heaven's sake. He that is able to receive it, let him receive it. - [Matthew 19: 10-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2019%3A10-12&version=KJV)

Comment: Children who die early in life (e.g the infants slaughtered on orders from Herod) would seem to indicate more strongly that some people aren't intended to be not single and lay. Their martyrology probably attests as to the will of God in this matter.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Good observation.

Comment: @KenGraham "_possibly_"? [1 Cor. 7:7](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=7&l=7-#x): "every one hath his proper gift from God". Also, [the state of celibacy/virginity is superior, more perfect than that of marriage](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.xi.html#v.i.i.xi-p5.6) (which passes away and doesn't exist in heaven; [Mt. 22:30](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=22&l=30-#x)), and Christ obliges all to strive toward perfection ([Mt. 5:48](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=5&l=48-#x): "Be you therefore perfect"), so He certainly intends some to be celibate now.

Comment: @Geremia Yes, but (aside from the other objections) it is possible that those people who are called to be perpetually virgin are *also* called to not be lay, hence the qualification "possibly".  However, if we also accept that God wills some die young and that those persons are clearly at least sometimes not called to be non-lay then that gives more certain proof that lay celibacy is not never a calling.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil What do you mean by "non-lay"? Priests? The religious?

Answer (score 3):

[Virginity and celibacy are superior states of life than that of marriage](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/70790/1787); and, though [one is not obliged to choose the greater good](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/70789/1787), all are obliged to strive toward perfection ([Mt. 5:48](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=5&l=48-#x): "Be you therefore perfect").

Those who try to find a wife but are unable are the second of the three types of eunuchs (unmarried people) that Christ enumerates in [Mt. 10:24](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=10&l=24-#x):

> For […] there are eunuchs, who were made so by men […].

The last sentence of this verse,

> He that can take [celibacy], let him take it.

doesn't command being unmarried, but recommends/[counsels](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/70789/1787) it.

We know that God intends some people to marry (else He wouldn't have created Eve) and some people to remain celibate:

[1 Cor. 7:7](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=7&l=7-#x):

> For I would that all men were even as myself [celibate]. **But every one hath his proper gift from God**: one after this manner, and another after that.

But ultimately marriage passes away, and everyone will be celibate in heaven:

[Mt. 22:30](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=22&l=30-#x):

> For in the resurrection they shall neither marry nor be married; but shall be as the angels of God in heaven.

Comment: This answer addresses well the issue of celibacy, but neglects to treat the issue of laity.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Celibacy = unmarried & continent. What do you mean by "laity"?

Comment: I mean the querent was excluding Religious (and maybe other people? It is unclear to me, is part of why I wasn't answering) from this.  Like, "does God ever want people to be celibate and not Religious?" And you said "He wants some people to be celibate" but you either need to say "and not Religious" or "but not not Religious". Personally I think there's strong evidence in both directions and it comes to a active/permissive will thing but idk so good luck ^^;

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Some people are called to [consecrated virginity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/71400/1787), [which is a vocation](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31311/31311-h/31311-h.htm#5); they're not bound by vows of obedience or poverty, so they're not [religious](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36033).